# Smallest Footprint PC Case

Tags: pc, case

I am looking for the smallest possible footprint PC Case to house the following components:

- Standard ATX power supply - Corsair CX600M
- Micro ATX motherboard - Gigabyte GA-A55M-DS2
- Dual slot graphics card - MSI GeForce GTX 750Ti
- 1 x 2.5" SSD
- 2 x 3.5" HDD - although I would be willing to drop down to 1 x 3.5" HDD.

The CPU Cooler and fan is only around 7cm high.

Ideally the case would be under £100.

Answer (score 1):

The [Silverstone SST-ML03B Milo ML03 HTPC](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/SilverStone-SST-ML03B-Micro-Silent-Computer/dp/B004HE2YZE/ref=psdc_430498031_t3_B01J1N43Y0) 
[image: picture with lid on]
[image: picture with lid off]

accepts your standard sized ATX power supply, costs 60 quid, and measures 43.99 x 33.99 x 10.49 cm.  10.5 cm when set on end is pretty small.

Comment: Putting one of these Home Theatre PCs its on its side is a great idea! However I am not sure my graphics card would fit in that. The PCI slots between the Motherboard and PSU are for low profile graphics card so it would not fit in those and the full length slot above the motherboard backplate is a single slot whereas my graphics card is a dual slot.